# How to handle JSON in static web server?

Tags: file, go, web, server, static

I have a simple static web server written in Go:

```
package main

import (
        "net/http"
        "log"
        "flag"
)

type myfs struct {
    http.Dir
}

func (m myfs) Open(name string) (result http.File, err error) {
    f, err := m.Dir.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    if fi.IsDir() {
        // Return a response that would have been if directory would not exist:
        return m.Dir.Open("does-not-exist")
    }
    return f, nil
}

func main() {
    directory := flag.String("d", "./static", "the directory of static file to host")
    handler := http.FileServer(myfs{http.Dir(*directory)})
//        http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
        http.Handle("/", handler)
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

It is serving all static files pretty well such as css, js, html and json. However just for JSON file, I want Go to come into the runtime, parse it and render a custom developed HTML code. The current handler function is an extension of http.FileServer, can I put my login in that?

Comment: What you are asking is an oxymoron. Parsing JSON and serving static files are, by definition, not compatible. You need to _not_ use the static server, and write a proper HTTP handler for your JSON.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to accomplish. So when a request to retrieve a `.JSON` file comes in, you want to return `HTML` instead?

Comment: @RodrigoCarvalho yes, example if json has content as { "city": "NJ" }, then I want to render it as <p>City: NJ</p>

Comment: That is, by definition, *not* static content. It is dynamically generated at runtime.

Comment: I agree with @Adrian. Also sounds a bit strange that user requests JSON and gets HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, what you want is to include the JSON inside of the HTML web page, correct?  If so, look at the [go "html/template"](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package.

You can modify your html file to be a template.

```
{{define "jsonInHTML"}}

{{ .InsertJSON }}

{{end}}
```

Then in your Go server handler

func rootHandler(wr http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

```
tmpl, err := template.New("name").Parse(...)

// Get the JSON form the body
InsertJSN, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)

// Execute the template passing the http.ResponseWriter, and the  
err := template.ExecuteTemplate(wr, "name", InsertJSON)
```

}